# smarty php in_array not working

Tags: smarty, smarty3

Smarty-3.1.20

Rewriting php webapp backend. Using Smarty because it was required a few years back, worked and why not but now it's wrecking my head. Nested template outputting checkboxes.

Why does the in_array return true if I paste one of the values as a string but not if I reference as a variable? Arrays are var_dump-ed and are arrays and {$otherArray[0]} returns correct variable. $anArray[loop] is printing the correct variable. No extra blanks in array strings. Stop me before I throw it all out, paste json into the bottom of the html and do it all with javascript (next time definitely)

tl;dr:

in_array is not returning true from a variable but is from a string?

```
<input type='checkbox' name='{$anArray[loop]}' value='{$anArray[loop]}' 
{if in_array($anArray[loop]}, $otherArray)} checked{/if}>
<br />
{$anArray[loop]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you don't use `$` sign here correctly, it should probably be:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='{$anArray[$loop]}' value='{$anArray[$loop]}' 
{if in_array($anArray[$loop]}, $otherArray)} checked{/if}>
<br />
{$anArray[$loop]}}
```

Comment: Interesting. Both these ideas return 'true' for the entire array, that is, all boxes are checked regardless of whether there is an array match. Note that {$anArray[loop]} - without the $ prefix on "loop" - returns the correct string to the template in the last line. I'm going to keep playing with this and will post if I solve it. I rewrote it in javascript for the job just to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
{if $anArray.$loop|in_array:$otherArray}checked{/if}
```